# Telerik RadWindow without NavigateURL?

Tags: telerik

I want a modal popup effect to display dynamic content on a single page.  I'm working with Telerik controls. Telerik has a control called RadWindow which is more  or less a modal window.

It looks like the only content that is to be displayed in RadWindow is the content of a page that is specified in NavigateURL. That is a problem for me because what I want to display is the dynamic content that I show on the same page.

Is it possible to display content that is on the same page using RadWindow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RadDock does what RadWindow does. Only, it takes input from the current page instead of from an external URL.

Answer (score 3):

The RadWindow is an iframe. It has to have a separate page to render, unless you use the clientside radalert and radconfirm methods--you can pass in HTML for an alert or confirm dialog that doesn't require a separate page. That doesn't sound like what you want. Consider using the RadToolTip or the AjaxToolkit ModalPopupExtender instead.

Comment: The RadWindow doesn't need a separate page to render. It has ContentTemplate tags and will render whatever HTML you place inside those tags.

Comment: You are correct. I'm not sure now if this is something that changed after I gave the answer or if I was simply mistaken, but my answer has not applied at least since GeorgiTunev gave his answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

For some time, RadWindow can display content from the main page as well. Here is a link to the demo:
http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/window/examples/internalcontent/defaultcs.aspx